# From path to File conversion with Flutter

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, cross-platform

I am working on a flutter project. I need to pick a file from device storage. I can get the path of the document but I need to save it as File or directly get it as File. To create path string I use **flutter_document_picker: 3.0.1**.

```
 Future getDocument(int index) async {
    var document = await FlutterDocumentPicker.openDocument();

    setState(() {
      if (document != null) {
        lstDocument[index] = document;
        Navigator.pop(context);
      }
    });
  }
```

Is there anyone know how can I save the *document* as File. Thanks for resolving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [flutter_absolute_path](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_absolute_path) to convert path to File().

```dart
    import 'package:flutter_absolute_path/flutter_absolute_path.dart';
    Future getDocument(int index) async {
        String documentLocation = await FlutterDocumentPicker.openDocument();
    
        if (documentLocation != null) {
          
          final document =
              await FlutterAbsolutePath.getAbsolutePath(documentLocation);
          File tempFile = File(document);
          setState(() {
            if (tempFile != null) {
              lstDocument[index] = tempFile;
              Navigator.pop(context);
            }
          });
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider/example) package to save the file to your phone.

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Future getDocument(int index) async {
  var document = await FlutterDocumentPicker.openDocument();

  setState(() {
    if (document != null) {
      lstDocument[index] = document;

      final String path = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory().path;

      // copy the file to a new path
      final File newImage = await image.copy('$path/image1.png'); // For Image Files

      Navigator.pop(context);
    }
  });
}
```